# How do I get the size of an HTML video element?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to convert the  element into a block and used element.clientWidth and element.clientHeight but that didn't work. How can I get the size of this element?

`<video style="display: block;"> video.clientWidth; video.clientHeight;`

Comment: if you have the element, try getboudingclientrect : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: is this what you are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement/videoWidth

Answer (score 1):

You can get an HTML element size with `element.offsetWidth` for width and `element.offsetHeight` for height.

```
document.getElementById('yourVideoElementID').offsetWidth
```

[Read docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth)